# What is the real-world performance of a Raspberry Pi 3 webserver?

Tags: web-server

On https://cheapskatesguide.org/articles/raspberry-pi-webserver.html, it says, "I recently had the opportunity to observe the performance of a Lighttpd web server running on a Raspberry Pi 3 while connected to the Internet under "heavy" load.  Visitors viewed a single, small html webpage containing 7KB of text and a 46KB jpg picture more than 20,000 times in a 12-hour period.  That is the equivalent of once every 2.16 seconds or 1.2 million times a month.  As far as I could tell, not only did the Raspberry Pi 3 not crash, it continued to run just fine with no significant slowdown.  I think this is proof that just about anyone who wants to run their own website with static or nearly static webpages from home should feel confident running it on a Lighttpd/Raspberry Pi 3 webserver."

Has anyone observed better real-world performance than this from a Raspberry Pi 3 Webserver?

Comment: *"Has anyone observed better real-world performance than this from a Raspberry Pi 3 Webserver?"* -> I would guess pretty much anyone who has bothered to stress test one.  If that load were distributed uniformly, at  rate of ~50K of static data every few seconds it's probably more or less idle.  In fact, I'd bet *any and all devices* capable of TCP networking and running a web server could do that.  Including, eg., a dollar store smart bulb.

Comment: I would also ask if the Pi is the AP as well. An old thread https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=241223 shows a limit on the WiFi side... Look to Flood.IO to simulate 500 User Hours or Loader.io to hit you with 1000 users both FOC and watch the Pi stop.  Also worth checking with your ISP that you are not in breach of contract AND no one is watching YouTube / playing games or surfing at the time :-)